# re-arrange multidimensional php array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I need to re-arrange a php multidimensional array so that to 'match' corresponding values from different arrays;

this is my reproducible example

```
<?php 

    // my original array
    $myar= array(
                array('A'=>'xxx','B'=>1),
                array('A'=>'yyy','B'=>2),
                array('A'=>'xxx','B'=>3),
                array('A'=>'yyy','B'=>4)
                );

    print_r($myar);

   // my desired result, new array
    $myar_new= array(
                array('xxx'=>1,'yyy'=>2),
                array('xxx'=>3,'yyy'=>4)
                );

    print_r($myar_new);


    ?>
```

any help for that?

thanks

Comment: What is the logic behind such grouping ? Why 1 and 2 are together and 1 and 4 are not ?

Comment: You need to show us what you have tried in order to solve this yourself, please also include any errors you ran into while doing this.

Comment: what if one item is `array('A'=>'zzz','B'=>1)`?

Comment: I want to select all values in key 'B' corresponding to the same values in key 'A'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I got your logic right then this function is what you need.

(Edited)

```
function strange_reformat($srcArray) {
    $newArray = [];
    $c = count($srcArray);
    $i = 0;
    $groupStart = null;
    $collect = [];
    while($i < $c) {
        $row = current($srcArray[$i]);
        if ($row == $groupStart) {
            $newArray[] = $collect;
            $collect = [];
        }
        $tmp = array_values($srcArray[$i]);
        $collect[] = [$tmp[0] => $tmp[1]]; 
        if ($groupStart === null) $groupStart = $row;
        $i++;
    }
    $newArray[] = $collect;

    return $newArray;
}

print_r(strange_reformat($myar));
```

Answer (score 0):

yes, that's it...

but now I need to generalise it, please consider this case

```
$myar= array(
            array('A'=>'xxx','B'=>1),
            array('A'=>'yyy','B'=>2),
            array('A'=>'zzz','B'=>5),
            array('A'=>'xxx','B'=>3),
            array('A'=>'yyy','B'=>4),
            array('A'=>'zzz','B'=>6)
            );
function strange_reformat($srcArray) {
    $newArray = [];
    $c = count($srcArray);
    for ($i=0; $i<$c; $i+=3) {
        $first = array_values($srcArray[$i]);
        $second = array_values($srcArray[$i+1]);
        $third = array_values($srcArray[$i+2]);
        $newArray[] = [$first[0]=>$first[1], $second[0]=>$second[1], $third[0]=>$third[1]];
    }

    return $newArray;
}

print_r(strange_reformat($myar));
```

Comment: in the above function $i can be any number of unique case value

Comment: So x/y/z can be an arbitary number of values? and are repeating twice (or more)? and a new Array value shall start after 50%? Or are gaps in the repeating pattern possible? Or does the "grouping" start when the first row is seen again? You have to define your source data in a clear way

Comment: yes, x/y/z can be any arbitrary number of values and they are repeating at least twice; the grouping should start when the first row of the pattern is seen again, thank you for all your efforts